# Bootstrap 4: Fix Image Being Outside of Div on Mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap to align image to the right of an image and all looks good on desktop, but on mobile the image is pushed outside of bootstrap column. I tried so many workarounds but none of them work. What might be causing this?

HTMLcode:

```
 <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 zee-section-col">
          <div class="col-spacer">
                 <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <h2>Lenevo ThinkPad Laptop</h2>
                    <a href="#">Buy Now - $820</a>

                  </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <img class="zee-section-prod-img img-responsive" src="https://www.cpsgroup.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/lenovo-laptop-thinkpad-e570-hero-1.png">
                  </div>

                 </div>
          </div>
        </div>

     </div>

  </div>
```

CSS:

```
 .col-spacer {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 7px 12px 5px #eee;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 7px 12px 5px #eee;
  box-shadow: 0 7px 12px 5px #eee;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 10px 20px 15px 20px;
  height: 310px;
}


.zee-section-col{
    padding-right: 2px !important;
    padding-left: 10px !important;
    padding-top: 15px !important; /* give padding top to inners*/
}

img{
  width: 100%;
}
```

This is how it looks on desktop:
[image]

But the image is pushed out on mobile as this shows:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change the CSS, removing the height constraint will stop you from running into further issues

```
.col-spacer {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 7px 12px 5px #eee;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 7px 12px 5px #eee;
  box-shadow: 0 7px 12px 5px #eee;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 10px 20px 15px 20px;
  /* height:310px;  */
}

.zee-section-col {
    /* padding-right: 2px !important; */
    /* padding-left: 10px !important; */
    padding-top: 15px !important;
}
```

After clarification I now know you want to have the Text underneath the image on mobile devices, but on all other devices you want the image to be on the right side of the text.

The following class means that this will not be shown (display:none) on XS and bigger screens

```
d-none
```

However this class means that everything sm and up will be display block

```
d-sm-block
```

Similarily, this class means that on sm sizes and up, nothing will be shown, therefore it will only display on xs sizes

```
d-sm-none
```

To do what you require, do the following

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row d-none d-sm-block">
        <div class="col-sm-6 zee-section-col">
          <div class="col-spacer">
                 <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <h2>Lenevo ThinkPad Laptop</h2>
                    <a href="#">Buy Now - $820</a>

                  </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <img class="zee-section-prod-img img-responsive" src="https://www.cpsgroup.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/lenovo-laptop-thinkpad-e570-hero-1.png">
                  </div>
                 </div>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row d-sm-none">
       <div class="col-12 zee-section-col">
         <div class="col-spacer">
           <div class="row">
             <div class="col-12">
               <img class="zee-section-prod-img img-responsive" src="https://www.cpsgroup.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/lenovo-laptop-thinkpad-e570-hero-1.png">
             </div>
             <div class="col-12">
               <h2>Lenevo ThinkPad Laptop</h2>
               <a href="#">Buy Now - $820</a>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

At the moment, on smaller screen sizes, your "sm" class is not being used, because the screen size of the mobile devices is smaller than what the "sm" class handles, in the past "xs" was used for mobile devices, however now it is the standard to just use the following for setting the mobile style

```
col-6
```

Screen sizes larger than "xs" then use

```
col-sm-6
col-md-6
col-lg-6
```

to adjust screen sizes at points greater than mobile, remember, mobile first :)

Assumably you are using Bootstrap 4 +

In this case, use the following to fix your issue

```
<div class="col-sm-6" >
```

Should become

```
<div class="col-6" >
```

If you are using Bootstrap 3.x

```
<div class="col-sm-6" >
```

Should become

```
<div class="col-xs-6" >
```

Comment: Yes, I tried the col-6 solution before but it does not stack divs on mobile?

Comment: Do you wish that on mobile, the image sits underneath the title or beside it?

Comment: Ideally, I would like the text to be underneath the image

Comment: Let me update my answer quickly to let you do that :) remember to vote :)

Comment: I am assuming you are using Bootstrap 4 in my answer, please advise if this is not the case

Comment: That works, but the nested column does not take the full width of the parent column on mobile

Comment: Which is the nested column that you are referring to

Comment: The whole nested row becomes so small comparing to the parent row on mobile

Comment: It does, however in your code you specified a 6 for the container not a 12

Comment: If you would like it on mobile to be a full width, full screen container i can change  my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192242/discussion-between-issmeil-el-and-chizzele).

Comment: Issue was with height and I am not sure how I did not spot that. I will mark your answer as correct provided that you update the code without using duplication and instead getting rid of the height using media queries...

Answer (score 0):

**col-sm** stack elements for small resolutions of screen. **col-*value*** create grid despite changing the screen resolution

```
    <div class="col-6">
         <h2>Lenevo ThinkPad Laptop</h2>
         <a href="#">Buy Now - $820</a>
    </div>


    <div class="col-6">
          <img class="zee-section-prod-img img-responsive" src="https://www.cpsgroup.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/lenovo-laptop-thinkpad-e570-hero-1.png">
    </div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options

Comment: Yes, I tried this solution before but it does not stack divs on mobile?